# Lazy Loader for Images which have URI Not URL android

Tags: android, image, uri, loader, lazy-evaluation

I have to load a list of all my phonebook contacts (which is around 1000+ contacts). Previously whenever I had such a large list I used to use Lazy Loader which uses URL for fetching images. But since Phonebook contacts' images are saved as URIs, I am having trouble finding the right lazy loader. I constantly get Out of memory exception. Please need help

Comment: have you tried to rewrite / adjust the lazy loader to load what you need to load?

Comment: yes I have...but I get stuck at some point...

Comment: How does a URI looks, pls post a simple string..